# Avoid my pointer to point invalid memory after variable gets out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code works (Visual Studio 2013)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class base {
    ...

    virtual ostream& toStream(ostream& str) const {
        str << "Data: " << this->getData() << " Changes: " << this->getChanges();

        return str;
    }
};

class A : public base { ... };

class B : public base { ... };

ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const base& base) {
    return base.toStream(str);
}

int main() {
    vector<base*> v(4);

    base myBase;
    B myB;

    {
        A myA;
        v[0] = &myBase;
        v[1] = &myA;
        v[2] = &myB;
        v[3] = v[1];
    }

    v[0]->setData(9);
    v[1]->setData(19);
    v[2]->setData(29);
    v[3]->setData(39);

    v[0]->setData(8);


    cout << "v[1]: " << v[1] << endl;
    cout << "v[3]: " << v[3] << endl;


    for each (base* b in v)
    {
        b->toStream(cout) << endl;
        cout << (*b) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Yet I know, `v[1] = &myA` is dangerous since myA gets destroyed at the end of the block.

But how can I do something like this without risks?

Is there any way to avoid the destruction of a variable's content which lays on the stack when the variable gets destroyed but the content still remains pointed by pointers?

EDIT:

Maybe something like this would is somewhat the same issue:

```
void addObject(object o) {
    this->myRefVector.push_back(&o);
}
```

Comment: What about `v[1] = new A;`? Or even better use shared pointers.

Comment: What do you mean with "something like this"?

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    A myA;
    v[0] = &myBase;
    v[1] = &myA;
    v[2] = &myB;
    v[3] = v[1];
}
```

Anything defined inside curly brackets no longer exists once the block exits. As far as i can see, these brackets serve no purpose - remove them, or initiate `myA` outside (before) the curly brackets

Comment: Then you need to specify that, as without explanation, it looks like they are present merely for clarity. Again i would suggest initiating `myA` outside the block, and asign the vector elements later

Answer (score 0):

How about creating the element objects first?

```
int main() {
    base myBase;
    A myA;
    B myB;

    vector<base*> v(4);

    v[0] = &myBase;
    v[1] = &myA;
    v[2] = &myB;
    v[3] = v[1];

    v[0]->setData(9);
    v[1]->setData(19);
    v[2]->setData(29);
    v[3]->setData(39)

    .
    .
    .
}
```

This way the container `v` is always destroyed before the objects it points to.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create the myA onject on heap and not on stack.

```
A* myA = new A();
```

but then you should change the assignment and delete the pointer after you're done using it.

```
{
// code
v[1] = myA;
// code
}
// code
// somewhere 
delete myA;
```

Or you can just remove those brackets. Or declare the myA outside of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a std::shared_ptr and a custom deleter to avoid deleting existing resources:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

void no_delete(void*) {};

int main() {

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<int> > v(4);

    // assign/create resources
    {
        v[0] = std::shared_ptr<int>(&a, no_delete);
        v[1] = std::shared_ptr<int>(&b, no_delete);
        v[2] = std::shared_ptr<int>(&c, no_delete);
        v[3] = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    }
}
```